# close upon backKeyPress windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, overriding, keypress

I have a problem. I have an popup that i want to close if the back key is pressed, now its closing the application. This it what i have done:

```
    protected override void OnBackKeyPress(CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dayselect.IsOpen == true)
        {
            dayselect.IsOpen = false;
            dayselectbackground.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }

        base.OnBackKeyPress(e);
    }
```

Now the application is closing as normal, what have i missed.

Comment: Actually is quite simple, you are just missing `e.Cancel = true`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by [SwiftSharp in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16414411/close-upon-backkeypress-windows-phone/16499474#comment23535712_16414411). =)

> Actually is quite simple, you are just missing `e.Cancel = true`